# getting `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)` when trying to deploy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, authlogic

I have the following line in my Gemfile:

`gem 'authlogic', :git => "git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git"`

When I push to heroku, I get the following error:

```
2013-07-29T15:09:28.895063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-29T15:09:32.231844+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 14117`
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic.rb:60:in `require': /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic/regex.rb:15: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic/regex.rb:15: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic/regex.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]: ...'(?:[A-Z]{2,4}|museum|travel|онлайн)'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic.rb:60:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic.rb:6:in `each'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.065084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.063805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/authlogic-e4b2990d6282/lib/authlogic.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:3:in `require'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064199+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.065084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.064496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-07-29T15:09:35.065084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-07-29T15:09:36.377852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-29T15:09:36.336374+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Of course, the app doesn't work.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this? Because at first sight, it might be from the AuthLogic (https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) code.

---

**UPDATE:**

OK. The weirdest thing just happened. It started by itself. It seems I just needed to give it some time and it's working now...

Leaving this here for people who encounter the same issue in the future.

However, it would be nice to know what's causing the AuthLogic error.

Comment: Can you add the full error? Or is this the only three lines outputed?

Comment: Looks like UTF-8 [TLDs and IDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) are going to be trouble across the board until people can get their character encoding issues sorted out.

Comment: tadman, please see comment on `sawa`'s answer -- I already explictly declared UTF-8 in all files.

Comment: Mab879, your wish is granted. Please see updated log above.

Comment: This has been [reported as an issue](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/pull/373).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that just replacing

```
gem 'authlogic', :git => "git://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic.git"
```

with

```
gem 'authlogic'
```

then

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle install
git push heroku master
```

causes the app to start.

Comment: No need to delete the entire lock file, to update a single gem run `bundle install --source authlogic`